# formatting issues with an attribute table in the QGIS Atlas

Tags: attribute-table, atlas

I'm having issues formatting an attribute table in the Atlas of QGIS. All the data are linked correctly, but the values and words are not centered in the middle of the rows (see picture). Changing the cell margins and lie width does not fix the problem. Under appearance, Display Header = 'on first frame', Empty tables = 'draw headers only', oversized text = 'wrap text'. Under Frames, I have "use existing frames" selected. And I have tried different combinations on the appearance, which don't seem to help. Does anyone know of a solution?
[image: image of current attribute table. trying to fix the values so they are centered in each row and not squished towards the top grid line.]

Comment: Also, the alignment within the "Attributes..." button is "middle" and not "top".